# Cantidad de usuarios logueados en mi web con devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Estoy utilizando devise para el manejo de sesiones en mi aplicación. Queria saber de que manera puedo realizar un count de la cantidad de usuarios logueados en mi web.

Ruby v.2.6.3 Rails v.5.2.4

Comment: [Primer resultado de google](https://www.google.com/search?q=devise+count+active+sessions) me arrojó [todas esas distintas opciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504130/whos-online-using-devise-in-rails). Prueba alguna

Comment: Amigo, ya tienes reputación en SOes como para saber que esta pregunta es muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Saber la cantidad de usuarios logeados no es algo recomendable porque puede tener fallos, ya que para identificar el login se almacena dentro de una cookie y esa cookie solamente se puede acceder en los navegadores de los usuarios.